# Drupal: customizing the look of WorkFlow module

Tags: drupal, workflow

Workflow module adds a workflow box to Edit node screen.
This box contains a list of available States for this node
and also such extra-options as:

> " Schedule: Immediately Schedule for
>   state change at: "

I don't want to confuse users with abundance of options and want to remove the last two (date related). 
Where should I customize this look of Edit screen and hide these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) hook can be used to modify the appearance of any Drupal form.

Here's a little pseudocode to get you started.

```
<?php

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'id_of_the_form') {
    unset($form['field_you_want_to_hide']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the workflow scheduling on the Permissions page.  On admin/user/permissions uncheck "schedule workflow transitions."